# What is the best way to implement an infinite loop with ThreadPoolExecutor?

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, threadpoolexecutor

My code makes use of ThreadPoolExecutor to process several tasks. One of the main requirements is that it executes indefinitely. This is my current implementation:

```
def process_something():
  with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=MAX_WORKERS1) as executor1:
    with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=MAX_WORKERS2) as executor2:
       while True:
          func1_returns = executor1.map(func1, arg1)
          func2_returns = executor2.map(func2, arg2)
    
          # code for processing func returns
    
          time.sleep(1)
```

Is there a better way to implement this? Will this be a possible memory leak since the executors reside in an infinite loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thread pool already has multiple threads to use. You don't need to create multiple pools.

```
def process_something():
  with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=MAX_WORKERS1) as executor1:
     while True:
        func1_returns = executor1.submit(func1, arg1)
        func2_returns = executor1.submit(func2, arg2)
    
        # code for processing func returns
    
        time.sleep(1)
```

There should not be any memory leak in the thread pool. The threads will be garbage collected when the `with` statement completes.

Comment: How will the garbage collector work though since the executor resides within an infinite loop  (while True)?

Comment: Good point. The executor will re-use the worker threads when you submit new tasks. All the threads will be destroyed when the process exits.